# take value from one html page to another

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want to take the value.university from my index.html to the universities.html page. How can I do this? Is this possible with maybe hidden value?

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">State</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">University</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="value in myDynamicData track by $index">
    <td>{{value.state}}</td>
    <td><a href="universities.html">{{value.university}}</a></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

A purely client-side approach would be to use `localStorage`, which stores a variable in the client browser. You can use:

```
var university = "some value here";
//creates a variable in the browser called university, which is now accessible from all pages of your website.
localStorage.setItem("university", university);
```

Now, in your second page:

```
var uni= localStorage.getItem("university"); //gets the value of "university" from localStorage
```

Comment: why do you want to use a localstorage for a simple value transfer from one page to other?

Comment: That's what localStorage is made for. Also, this is just one possible approach, yours is also pretty neat.

Comment: do i need to put the first one into my separated javascript ?

Comment: @Annelie the first code block should run in your first page, i.e. index. Therefore, place this code block in whatever javascript file you have that runs in index.html (or create a `<script>` tag)

Comment: The important is that you set the localStorage variable in your first page, and be able to access it in your second page

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="myTable">
                <tr class="header">
                  <th style="width:60%;">State</th>
                  <th style="width:40%;">University</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="value in myDynamicData track by $index">
                  <td>{{value.state}}</td>
                  <td><a href="universities.html?vu={{value.university}}">{{value.university}}</a></td>
                </tr>
             </table>
```

Then in the universities.html you can read using window.location.search

Comment: may i know the reason for down voting?

Comment: When I use this, the link isn't a hyperlink anymore

Comment: Do you know why this is?